# Golf swing segmentation from time-series data

Tags: time-series, signal-processing, timeseries-segmentation

I need to identify golf swings in a set of time-series motion capture data. The following illustrates the captured Y-values (in video pixels) of a person's left hand over a period of about 10 seconds, with segments annotated:

EDIT: To be more clear, I only care about segmenting the actual swing from all other motion. The other annotations in the image below (walking, setup) are for illustration purposes only.

[image: swing]

A swing will typically consist of a local minimum (takeaway), followed by a maximum (top of backswing), followed by another minimum (impact), followed by another maximum (top of follow-through).

Like the example above, the data may include a person's various movements before and after the swing.

What methods can I use to automatically segment a single swing from noisy data like this?

Comment: What is the background behind this dataset and the application for it? How do you get the data for those left hand pixels? Is this like doing sports biomechanical analysis, or is this for help in broadcasting video's for TV? Why do you want to analyse these time series and why do you only have only data for the left hand? Also what amount of data do you have? What sort of analysis do you want to eventually make? Example I imagine that the screen motion capture data is a feasibility study and you want to eventually want to apply it to data from a smart watch and require a lean algorithm.

Comment: The goal is to automatically identify and crop a golf swing from continuous video. I do have positional data for all (visible) joints; showing hand position is just an example, and happens to be the joint with the most easily-identifiable pattern. (Left and right hand positions are virtually identical for golf swings). Processing speed is not a major concern.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what level of automation you wish to achieve. I would say that sooner than later you will still need some ground truth dataset to validate your model. It is very unlikely that you will be able to reach, e.g., 95% accuracy with a simple formula for detecting the pattern in a data (like thresholding algorithm). I would suggest you split your dataset into same-duration time periods. e.g., swing lasts for 5 sec - then take 5 sec time intervals, define some labels for these intervals, then (down/up)sample your data from particular frames to have, e.g., 100 samples for 5 sec duration, then try to use ML/DL (e.g., SVM), or linear regression even, to categorize your time interval as either: walk, setup/rest, swing. If that will not work, increase the number of samples in your learning dataset and/or try some approaches taking the time into account, such as LSTMs.

I mean, you can use some zero (or X) crossing two-factor thresholding, but then you need to do some proper testing, either cross-validation or empirical testing to be sure that your algorithm works fine.

If you have raw video available, maybe it will be better to use some posture-processing algorithm to get more joints (https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/trt_pose), rather than focus only on the left hand -- it could be very complicated to get the proper model from left hand alone.

Comment: I edited my question to be a little more clear: I don't care about categorizing the different types of motion, rather I just need to separate the swing motion from everything else. Hopefully this makes the problem easier. And yes, I do have positional data for all joints... however hand positions produce the most "obvious" pattern visually, compared to e.g. lower body which doesn't noticeably move.

Comment: It is still one type of motion vs. the rest, my answer still applies. That makes the problem easier, indeed, but still, you need a validation set. I was thinking more of head position (to distinguish from bowing down), the right hand, to distinguish from weaving and making gestures with hands -- the kinds of moves that for the left hand alone can be mistook for a swing. If you have only data from an experimental/laboratory-like conditions, in which you have only short videos of swings, I would use a double threshold algorithm that should work for 90-95% of cases.

Comment: Ok, suppose we want to take advantage of multiple joints (hands, head, shoulders, legs, etc). What kind of algorithm would you suggest? Training an ML model might be unrealistic due to lack of labeled training data, so I'm ok with a classical algorithm that I can hand-tune to be "good enough." Your help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use algorithmic approach, instead of ML, I would start with thresholding: different threshold for different joints, maybe some normalization as data preprocessing (0-1 range, or z-scoring), then for the most important joint, e.g., for the left hand/wrist, I would give two thresholds in two different timepoints.

--- If certain thresholds for particular joints are reached (+/- time separation, i.e., time delta between thresholds for the same or different joints), then the movement is classified as a swing.